# Edit tags needs a refresh to show the user who edited

Tags: bug, inline-tag-editor

Today I tried editing the tags using "edit tag" option for 10K users.

1. Update a tag -> SAVED
2. It didn't show my name.
3. After a refresh, it showed my name.

Below are the screenshots for clear explanation.

[image]

Is this the exact behavior?

Comment: Reproduced in this question. Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m

Comment: latest version of chrome, FF in windows8

Comment: I've noticed this as well since I reached 10K.  Always assumed it was by design because of the inline editing.

Comment: If you think it's not working as designed (but it probably is), make it a [tag:bug] (and leave yourself open to simply getting a [meta-tag:status-bydesign] tag, instead of a fix). If you think it is working as designed and you want it changed, make it a [tag:feature-request] instead.

Comment: Why did you remove the tag [inline-tag-editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inline-tag-editing)?

Comment: It was always like that, the tag list to the right also does not update.

Comment: @hims056 10k tools refer to [this page and its sub pages](http://stackoverflow.com/tools) as far as I know, not to any privilege we get at 10K. :)

Comment: Adding feature request since it's not really a bug, rather request to change current behavior.

Comment: The in-page editor does do a proper refresh after an edit, IMHO there's no reason why the inline tag editor should be different.